# Is it possible to rewrite the following code without using .doubleValue()?

Tags: java

so I'm trying to write a method which uses generics. The method is suppose to takes a arrayList and return the highest value in the array. Here is the code to do that

```
 public T largest() {
    T value = myList.get(0);
    for (int i = 1; i < myList.size(); i++) {
        if (myList.get(i).doubleValue() > value.doubleValue()) {
            value = myList.get(i);
        }
    }
    return value;
}
```

Only problem is I'm not suppose to use .doubleValue. I've been stuck trying to figure it out for hours with no luck, Generics are reallyyyyy throwing me off for some reason. Am I suppose to somehow cast something? How can I write that above method without using .doubleValue()? Thanks!

Comment: So the item type is `Number`? Are you allowed to use the given sort methods from the Java API?

Comment: `T` `extends` `Number` right?

Comment: It can be done with <T extends Comparable<T>> which covers the number cases and also e.g. a List<String>.

Comment: @Tom Yes the final value returned will be a type that is below Number (one arrayList will be a Integer and one will be a Double). No I' am not allowed to use anything from Collections if that is what you are referring to.

Comment: I assumed your `myList` was going to be of a class implementing java.util.List, but that involves Collections. What is the type of myList?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan So the method header should be "public <T extends Comparable<T>> highest () " ? For some reason I'm getting a compile error  when it is like that. Only thing I have imported in my myList class is import java.util.ArrayList;

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/boundedTypeParams.html - this part of the generics tutorial should help

Comment: Don't worry, generics are often throwing off even seasoned developers.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what they had in mind when giving you this task.
The elements of your list need to be something that is `Comparable`.
This way you can compare them simply by calling `compareTo`.
This implementation is more general, more generic.
That is you don't need to limit yourself to using `doubleValue` in particular.

```
package test;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Test001 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Long a = largest(Arrays.asList(new Long[]{2L, 5L, 7L}));
        Integer b = largest(Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{2, 5, 7}));
        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println(b);
    }

    public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> T largest(List<T> myList) {
        T value = myList.get(0);
        for (int i = 1; i < myList.size(); i++) {
            if (myList.get(i).compareTo(value) > 0) {
                value = myList.get(i);
            }
        }
        return value;
    }

}
```

Comment: This helped, thanks! The only problem is I also have a method which  takes a parameter of type T and adds it to the arraylist. I'm then suppose to take THAT array and find the largest value in it. Is it a way I can have that same method without using parameters, only the passedArray from the eailer method?

Comment: Btw, I am intentionally using `T extends Comparable<? super T>` and not `<T extends Comparable<T>>`

Comment: @ComputerScience Why is that a problem? Not sure what you mean.

Comment: Is it a way I can have that same method without using parameters, only using the "passedArray" from the earlier method? When I take out the parameters, I get an error saying " cannot convert from T extends Number to T extends Comparable<? super T> " and another one saying "The method compareTo(T) is undefined for the type T"

Comment: OK, the problem here is that Number does not extend Comparable. Define that other method to be compliant with my method. Then you can do what you want. Otherwise that other method is more general and you cannot do it.

Answer (score 2):

You can only find the largest element if an ordering of the elements is defined. Since you're got giving a `Comparator` to the method to specify such an order, you're assuming "natural order", which means the elements must be `Comparable`.

Your function changes to the following (changed to `static` to make this standalone answer "complete"):

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T largest(Iterable<T> myList) {
    T largest = null;
    for (T value : myList)
        if (largest == null || value.compareTo(largest) > 0)
            largest = value;
    return largest;
}
```